# How to parse through strings and highlight differences in C++

Tags: c++

I have two strings I want to compare, example "1001" and "1010". And I want to compare them and and then have an output print and highlight the differences maybe with a new color or with a different font. I have examined the ASCII escape character library. So I can color output, but I only want the differences highlighted in the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#define RESET "\033[0m"
#define GREEN   "\033[32m"
#define UNDER "\033[4m"



using namespace std;

string str_1 = "0110000110";
string str_2 = "0100101001";
string str_Dif = "";

int main(){
int i = 0;
int dif = 0;
for (i = 0; i < str_1.size(); i++){
    if (str_1[i] != str_2[i]){
        str_2[i] = "\033[32m";
        str_Dif += str_2[i];
        dif++;

    }
    else{
        str_Dif += str_2[i];
    }


}
    std::cout << str_1 + "\n";
    std::cout << str_2 + "\n";
    std::cout << UNDER << GREEN << str_Dif << RESET << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "The differences: " + to_string(dif) + "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said anything about your code. Does it not work? Where do you see the problem(s)? It's not clear to me where you need help.

Comment: `str_2[i] = "\033[32m";` doesn't work. `"invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'"`. You can use `const char *color = GREEN; str_2[i] = *color;`

Comment: If that's the only problem, the topic is just a distraction. Please, extract a [mcve] first. As a new user, also make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: There's no reason to use `#define` here!

Answer (score 1):

You might use the following:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>
highlight_diff(const std::string& ref, const std::string& s)
{
    std::string res;
    std::size_t count = 0;
    auto it_ref = ref.cbegin();
    auto it = s.cbegin();

    while (it_ref != ref.cend() && it != s.cend()) {
        auto p = std::mismatch(it_ref, ref.cend(), it, s.end());
        res.insert(res.end(), it_ref, p.first);
        std::tie(it_ref, it) = p;
        p = std::mismatch(it_ref, ref.cend(), it, s.end(), std::not_equal_to<>{});
        if (p.first != it_ref) {
            count += p.first - it_ref;
            res += GREEN;
            res.insert(res.end(), it_ref, p.first);
            res += RESET;
        }
        std::tie(it_ref, it) = p;
    }
    if (it != s.end()) {
        count += s.end() - it;
        res += GREEN;
        res.insert(res.end(), it, s.end());
        res += RESET;
    }
    return {res, count};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd1c24f9f17ae1d)